# MySQL Group on Condition

Tags: mysql

Suppose I've got the following table:

```
 time_recorded        |   room   | num_occupied
 ----------------------------------------------
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       a          10
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       b          20
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       c          30
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       d          40

 2012-11-05 00:30:00       a          100
 2012-11-05 00:30:00       b          200
 2012-11-05 00:30:00       c          300
 2012-11-05 00:30:00       d          400
                     ...
```

I need to group the rows when rooms = 'b' and 'c', so that the resulting output would be

```
 time_recorded        |   room   | num_occupied
 ----------------------------------------------
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       a          10
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       bc       (20+30)
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       d          40

 2012-11-05 00:30:00       a          100
 2012-11-05 00:30:00       bc      (200+300)
 2012-11-05 00:30:00       d          400
                     ...
```

I tried the following query, suggested by *juergen d*:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    usage
WHERE 
    DATE(time_recorded) = '2012-11-05'
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN room IN ('b', 'c') THEN 'bc' ELSE room END;
```

For some reason I get the following returned:

```
 time_recorded        |   room   | num_occupied
 ----------------------------------------------
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       a          10
 2012-11-05 00:00:00       b          20
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if there is no b but only c in that column?

Comment: Suppose this never happens...

Comment: For some reason it stops execution at the first room b it encounters. I want it to merge rooms b and c everywhere where date is 2012-11-05 (please, see a bit above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by a computed value but not displaying that value.

You need to place the `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause too, along with a computed field to show the value of `num_occupied`. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
   time_recorded, CASE WHEN room IN ('b', 'c') THEN 'bc' ELSE room END, 
    SUM(num_occupied)
FROM 
   usage
WHERE 
    DATE(time_recorded) = '2012-11-05'
   GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

(edited per comment)

Comment: Well, thank you, it almost works, but for some reason it returns only one sequence (when the time_recorded = '2012-11-05 00:00:00'), but not others (for example, when time_recorded = '2012-11-05 00:30:00').

Comment: In that case, add `DATE(time_recorded)` to the group by clause, for example by saying `GROUP BY 1, 2`